# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable serializer Django Serializer for one-to-many

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am facing a strange situation, Following is my code for models.

```
class Sector(models.Model):
    sector_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    sector_desc = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False)

    def __set__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.sector_name, self.sector_desc)


class TrailCompany(models.Model):
    sector = models.ForeignKey(Sector, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sector_id")
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    comp_desc = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False)

    def __set__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.sector, self.comp_name, self.comp_desc)


class Trail(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(TrailCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="company_id")
    trail_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    tri = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    exp_pdufa = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __set__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.company, self.exp_pdufa, self.trail_id, self.tri, self.exp_pdufa)
```

Following is my code for the serializer,

```
class SectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Sector
        fields = '__all__'


class TrailCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sectors = SectorSerializer(source="sector_id", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TrailCompany
        fields = '__all__'


class TrailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companies = TrailCompanySerializer(source="company_id", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Trail
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I try to serilize object I am getting the stated error,

```
trail_query = Trail.objects.all()
        trails = TrailSerializer(trail_query, many=True)
        return Response({"success": True, 'trails': trails.data})
```

Please help me to figure out and resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: Dear When I try go to `/api/home_meta` it is throwing `TypeError at /api/home_meta 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your error is in the following line:

```
companies = TrailCompanySerializer(source="company_id", many=True)
```

Trail<>TrailCompany is a one to one relationship from the perspective of Trail. E.g. the Trail only knows of one TrailCompany it is related to. Therefore you do not need the `many=True` attribute.

I also think the source should be `company` rather than `company_id`. `company_id` is a primary key, whereas `company` is the related object

Answer (score 0):

Selected answer doesn't work for me. However following way worked:

```
company = TrailCompanySerializer(many=True)
```

Also remember to put `company` in `related_name` field like this:

```
company = models.ForeignKey(TrailCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="company")
```